# Request Oracle PLSQL ACCEPT-PROMPT in Date Format using Date Picker?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, toad

I need the following SQL sentence to prompt for `From_Date` variable in a DATE format. Currently, Toad (the tool I'm using) marks it as a 'Substitution' variable. I understand this should be enough to have Toad include a Date Picker in my prompt.

```
ACCEPT From_Date FORMAT DATE
PROMPT 'Enter from date: '

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('&From_Date');

END
;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PLSQL does not and cannot prompt ever. You are mixing to concepts:

1. Bind Variables: Passing a variable from a script into PLSQL
2. Substitution Variables: A "variable" that is physically replaced by the interface in your script **before** being sent to Oracle.

Your scripts sets up a Bind Variable with ACCEPT-PROMPT and a substitution variable with &From_Date. You need to choose 1 not mix them, at least for the same variable. Try the following:

Use bind variable:

```
ACCEPT From_Date FORMAT DATE
PROMPT 'Enter from date: '
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (':From_Date');
END;
```

Use substitution variable:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('&From_Date');
END;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately not it's not prompting for a value anymore. Current results are: 'Enter from date: ' / :From_Date / PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.